# jQuery fresh ALL rows from PHP loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Im not sure what is happening here, but I can not update this DIV per every row using this code. This code loads a initial user list, and loads the rest (after first 3) to a DIV dropdown triggered by click event.

```
<? foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
```

```
                        <script>
                        function fetchIndexUsers() {
                            $(function () {});
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/ajax/ajax_live_index_users.php',
                                method: 'GET',
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                data: { 
                                    item_id: <?=intval($row["item_id"])?>
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var html_to_append = '';
                                    array = [];
                                    results = [];
                                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                        results[i] = data[i];
                                        array[0] = item.total;
                                        array[1] = item.calc;
                                        let icon = item.user.match(/(^|\W)yes($|\W)/i) ? 'arrow_upward' : 'arrow_downward';
                                        html_to_append += '<div style="display:inline;float:left"><span class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:top;width:16px;padding-right:30px;color:#c0c0c0">' + icon + '</span></div><div style="display:inline;float:left;padding-bottom:1px"><a class="tooltip-newusers" title="' + item.username + '" href="/user/?id=' + item.user_id + '"><img style="box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #D3D3D3;height:35px;width:35px;border-radius:50%;margin-bottom:6px;margin-right:-20px;margin-top:-5px;vertical-align:middle;position:relative;z-index:10005;border:2px solid #FFF" src="/' + item.avatar + '" /></a></div><div style="clear:both"></div>';
                                        return i <= 3;
                                    });
                                    if (array[0] >= 3) {
                                        $("#live-peers-more-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").html('<div id="slidedown-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>" style="user-select:none;margin-top:-14px;position:absolute;right:-20px;font-size:13px;background:purple;padding:0 6px;text-align:center;border-radius:3px;color:#FFF;font-weight:500;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #D3D3D3"><a style="color:#fff;cursor:pointer">+ ' + (array.length - array[1]) + (array[1] >= 2 ? ' peers' : ' peer') + '</a></div>')
                                        if (array[1] === 0) {
                                            $("#live-users-more-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").hide();
                                        }
                                    }                                   
                                    $("#live-users-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").html(html_to_append);
                                    $('.tooltip-newusers').tooltipster({
                                        animation: 'grow',
                                        delay: 200,
                                        interactive: true,
                                        theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
                                    });
                                    $("#live-peers-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").css('background', 'none');    
                                    $("#slidedown-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").html('<span><a style="color:#fff;cursor:pointer">+ ' + array[0] + (array[0] >= 2 ? ' peers' : ' peer') + '</a></span>');                                       
                                }
                            });                     
                            $("#live-users-more-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").click(function () {
                                $("#slidedown-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").css('z-index', '9999999');
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/ajax/ajax_live_index_users.php',
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    cache: false,
                                    dataType: 'JSON',
                                    data: { 
                                        item_id: <?=intval($row["item_id"])?>,
                                        more: 1
                                    },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        var html_to_append = '';
                                        $.each(results, function (i, item) {
                                            html_to_append += '<div id="more_users" style="padding:6px;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3)"><div id="peer-username">' + truncateString(item.username, 6) + '</div><a class="tooltip-newusers" title="' + item.username + '" href="/user/?id=' + item.user_id + '"><img style="height:35px;width:35px;border-radius:50%;border:2px solid #FFF" src="/' + item.avatar + '" /></a><div style="font-size:11px;font-weight:normal">' + formatBytesSpeed(item.totalspeed) + '</div></div>';
                                            $("#slidedown-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").css('height', 'auto');
                                        });
                                        $("#slidedown-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>").html(html_to_append);
                                        $('.tooltip-newusers').tooltipster({
                                            animation: 'grow',
                                            delay: 200,
                                            interactive: true,
                                            theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        fetchIndexUsers();
                        setInterval(function () {
                            fetchIndexUsers()
                        }, 5000);
                        </script>
```

```
<div id="live-users-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>" style="padding:10px;background:url(/images/loading-ellipsis.svg) no-repeat left">
    <span style="padding-right:89px"></span>
</div>
<div id="live-users-more-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>"></div>
```

```
<? } ?>
```

But any action coming back only updates the last row in from the array (PHP foreach array, with the JS emedded in the loop picking up on the ID from the iteration).

How come it only interacts with the last row? How can I update all rows since I am using a unique ID?

Thank you

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]`  stacksnippet and format your code. If you really have all that javascript INSIDE a php loop, then that is really poor coding style

Comment: Then there lies the problem, and I look forward to a solution.

Comment: is there no data-attribute or something similar to simply match the IDs with the ajax response and update outside of the loop, like we usually do?

Comment: Thank you - I got it working perfectly with what you provided, and using data-id then I used a Each loop on the div set and wrapped that all in a document load event and its flawless! Much appreciated

Comment: You are welcome. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the script out from the loop completely. Have ONE version of the script that delegates like this

```
$("#container").on("click", ".live-users-more",function () { 
  const item_id = $(this).prev().attr("id");  ....
```

and then change

```
<div id="live-users-more-<?=intval($row["item_id"])?>"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="live-users-more"></div>
```

where you have a

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

that wraps all the live user divs